# Debugging Fabricjs visually

Tags: fabricjs

Is it possible to enable some kind of flag to give outline of all fabric js objects to be able to debug visually where items are placed.

I have tried:

```
 this.canvas?.getObjects().forEach(obj => {
        obj.set({
          strokeWidth: 2,
          stroke: 'red',
        });
      });
```

But this doesn't seem to work on my groups. I am hoping that fabric has some integrated feature for this.

Answer (score 1):

See http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html#forEachObject

here is how i would use this :

```
this.canvas?.getObjects().forEach(obj => {
    obj.set({
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 2,
  });

  if(obj.type.toLowerCase() === 'group') {
    obj.forEachObject((children) => {
      children.set({
          stroke: 'red',
          strokeWidth: 2,
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I would 2 but objects have objects so i would make it recursive. I was hoping there is something better by fabricjs team

Comment: You could always extend fabric.Group with your own class take look at my example [link](https://codepen.io/DocAMZ/pen/zYbJQKr)

Comment: that would be the best way